# Is it possible to define a Proxied URL for the "Github-URL" in renovate-runner?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, renovate

We want to use the renovate-runner project (https://gitlab.com/renovate-bot/renovate-runner/) to enable auto-dependency updates in our self hosted Gitlab projects.

All reqeusts from gitlab to external services have to be proxied via Nexus. We already configured this successfully for npm and maven registries.
However renovate also requests Github.com to fetch Release Notes of new dependency versions. (e.g. Fetching changelog: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct (1.4.0.Final -> 1.4.2.Final)

These requests fail as we are not able to request github.com directly.
Is there any way to configure these release note requests?

Answer (score 1):

You can not proxy this requests through your nexus, but you can proxy them through your HTTP proxy using the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` env variables